# I already installed express by "npm install express" command. But Still Getting ERROR

Tags: node.js

I can install npm packages normally, and I already installed express by "npm
install express" command.
This is the app.js file am trying to run:

```
/* app.js */
var app = require('express').createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

`c:\> node app.js`

This is the Error:

```
node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/app.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at Object.runMain (node.js:522:24)
    at Array.<anonymous> (node.js:756:12)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:55:22)
    at node.js:773:9
```

Question, Whats wrong step I am following?

This is the output after installing express:

```
C:\MYSite>npm install express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-2.7.2.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-2.7.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.5.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.5.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/-/formidable-1.0.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/-/formidable-1.0.11.tgz
express@3.1.0 node_modules\express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
├── cookie@0.0.5
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── commander@0.6.1
├── debug@0.7.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.3
├── send@0.1.0 (mime@1.2.6)
└── connect@2.7.2 (pause@0.0.1, bytes@0.1.0, formidable@1.0.11, qs@0.5.1)
```

Comment: You did not install express with npm, please tell us what's npm's input after running npm install express

Comment: Your question is not so clear... Update with the few more details..

Comment: Just updated the output after express install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed express locally, not globally

> C:\MYSite>npm install express

So you have to run from this `MYSite` folder only. But you are running it from different location.

> C:> node app.js

Hence it keeps giving error `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

Answer (score 0):

Even with global install if you have used Homebrew to install node you will still have an issue.

You can fix it by doign the following:

```
brew uninstall node
```

and then install node using the installer on the nodejs.org site.

Then run:

```
npm install -g express
```

Hope this helps someone.